# QEMU img convert invalid parameter

Tags: vmware-workstation, terminal, command, vmware-vmdk

Typing the command:

`qemu-img convert -o vmdk /path/file.VHDX ~/path/file.VMDK`

Returns response:
qemu-img: Invalid parameter 'vmdk'

I'm converting a Windows 11 Client ARM64 into a VMDK file for my VM.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably read the man page.

From `man qemu-img`:

> convert [-c] [-p] [-f fmt] [-t cache] [-O output_fmt] [-o options] [-S sparse_size] filename [filename2 [...]] output_filename

Use `-O vmdk` to specify output format. `-o` is used to specify further options.